# Glue Table partition projection and crawlers

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

Is it possible to have partition projections for tables that are created by Glue crawlers ?

If so, what will happen if the crawler update the table ?

Partition projection :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection-setting-up.html

Crawlers :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/add-crawler.html